# Calculation of commutation relations in the SYK model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, symmetry, commutator

I'm reading this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07818). And I'm having trouble showing an equality. We consider the following $SL(2,R)$ generators.
\begin{align}
D=-t\partial_t-\frac{1}{4},\ P=\partial_t,\ K=t^2\partial_t+\frac{1}{2}t.
\end{align}
It seems that this can be exchanged with the following function $K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$, but I don't get it.
\begin{align}
K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)=\frac{{\rm sgn}(t_1-t_3)}{\sqrt{|t_1-t_3|}}\frac{{\rm sgn}(t_2-t_4)}{\sqrt{|t_2-t_4|}}\frac{1}{|t_3-t_4|}.
\end{align}
The exchange relation is said to be as follows, except for up to the total derivative term.
\begin{align}
(P_1+P_2)K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)&=K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)(P_3+P_4)\\
(D_1+D_2)K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)&=K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)(D_3+D_4)\\
(K_1+K_2)K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)&=K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)(K_3+K_4)
\end{align}
where the subscript of the generator means that it is the derivative with respect to $t_i$. I'd be grateful if someone could give me some specific calculations or hints, just for the simplest case $P$.